# Ошибки Cannot read property 'fn' и Uncaught TypeError: $(...) - как исправить?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress, format

Есть [на wordpress сайте страница калькулятора](http://www.xn--24-6kcajs6adxi.xn--p1ai/calculator/), где подключена [библиотека formatter.js](https://github.com/jaridmargolin/formatter.js) для корректного ввода телефона по патерну. Но,
захожу на страницу и которую получаю ошибки вида:

> jquery.formatter.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'fn' of undefined
>
> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).formatter is not a function

В связи с чем они возникли? Вроде как все в шаблоне подключаю грамотно после объявления `jquery`.

**Код functions.php**

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
function my_scripts_method(){
    if ( is_page('calculator') ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'formatter-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/jquery.formatter.min.js',array('jquery'),null,true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/scripts.js',array('jquery'),null,true);
    }
}
```

**Код scripts.js** где вызываю `formatter`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('.promo_phone_class').val('+7');
    $('.promo_phone_class').keyup(function(e) {
        if((e.keyCode == 8) || (e.keyCode == 46)) {
            if($(this).val() == '') {
                $(this).val('+7');
            }
        }
    });
    $('.promo_phone_class').formatter({
        'pattern': '+7({{999}}){{999}}-{{99}}-{{99}}',
        'persistent': false
    });
    $('[field=phone]').formatter({
        'pattern': '({{999}}){{999}}-{{99}}-{{99}}',
        'persistent': false
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress использует jQuery noConflict mode. Именно поэтому первая строка вашего файла выглядит как `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {`, чтобы внутри него использовать символ `$` вместо `jQuery`.

`jQuery.formatter.js`, однако, сразу пытается использовать символ `$` в своём коде, не предполагая, что jQuery может быть запущен в noConflict mode.

Попробуйте взять исходный код `jquery.formatter.js` и заменить в нём `$` на `jQuery`. Подключение скриптов будет выглядеть так:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'formatter-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/jquery.formatter.js',array('jquery'),null,true);
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/scripts.js',array('jquery', 'formatter-js'),null,true);
```

Обратите внимание на отсутствие `min` в первой строке и зависимость от formatter во второй.

Comment: супер, заработало! Спасибо